# Top of ScrollView hidden behind status bar

Tags: android, android-layout, statusbar, android-scrollview

I have a `FrameLayout`  which contains `ImageView` for background and `LinearLayout` within `ScrollView` to display all of the Views I need. Simplified code is displayed below and is used for my `Fragment`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ink"
        android:scaleType="center"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

   </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

This fragment is put within `FrameLayout` of my `activity_main.xml` which looks like this

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >
</FrameLayout>
```

When sum of item heights become bigger than height of the screen `ScrollView` kicks in and I can scroll all the items I have within `LinearLayout` like expected.

The problem is that when I scroll to top of the `LinearLayout`, the uppermost View is hidden behind status bar like in this picture:

[image]

The behavior I'm looking for is this:

[image: The top of the view is below the status bar and fully visible.]

How can I accomplish the result shown in the second image?

My styles.xml is as follows

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the style definition for the theme this activity is using?

Comment: Does it work correctly on an actual device or emulator?

Comment: Hmm... not what I expected to see. Just in case, does adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the root framelayout fix it?

Comment: I actually already had `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to my root `FrameLayout`. When I run this on actual device the same thing happens as in preview except when I rotate device to landscape view even bigger part is hidden behind top of the device and I cant scroll it down. On the other hand bottom has extra padding maybe the same size as top is missing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the rules to follow:

- Don't use `android:layout_gravity` attribute on children of `ScrollView`.

  - It produces unwanted behavior, see comments for details.
- Don't use `android:layout_height="match_parent"` on children of `ScrollView`

  - The child doesn't want to be as big as the screen (scroll view viewport). The whole point is the child has a precise height or wants to expand to fit its own contents.
  - While `match_parent` may behave as `wrap_content` for children of scroll views, philosophically it makes no sense here.

If you need to center the content on the whole screen *and* allow scrolling when it doesn't fit, use this setup:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Etc. -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`android:fillViewport="true"` expands the child if its smaller than the scroll view.

Notice the missing `layout_` prefix in `android:gravity`.

- `android:gravity` tells the `LinearLayout` how to position its own children inside itself.
- `android:layout_gravity` tells *whoever the parent is* (here `ScrollView`) how to position the `LinearLayout` within the parent.

Comment: wow this is working, u saved me hours of trying to figure this out :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: no problem! check out the edit for better explanation

Comment: @EugenPechanec I'm a little confused by "If I were the scroll view I don't even know how I would calculate the child's position". ScrollView is a subclass of FrameLayout and FrameLayout has no problem interpreting `layout_gravity` attributes. Personally I'd expect `layout_gravity` to function just like it would in FrameLayout when the content is smaller than the ScrollView, and to have no effect at all when the content is larger than the ScrollView.

Comment: @BenP. I'm not going to try to unwind the implementation of ScrollView, that's way above my paygrade. We can argue about what `android:layout_height="match_parent"` means inside a widget that's theoretically infinite in height, we can argue about what "center" is in infinite space. Is it the center of the viewport/screen? Is it the center of the content? And again what's the center of the content if we can't measure it's height because `match_parent` is undefined? **Let's just call the behavior "undefined"** and remember the two rules I mentioned above.

Comment: @EugenPechanec "inside a widget that's theoretically infinite in height" sounds like handwaving to me. The ScrollView has a definite height, just like every other view in the hierarchy. Simply blindly following rules will never work as well as truly understanding _why_ those rules are correct.

Comment: 1/2 @BenP. Alright, children are positioned by their parents and `layout_` attributes are a way how children tell their parent how they *want to be* positioned, correct? Now let's get into what happens in the ScrollView. First of all, **when the contents *are measured* smaller than the viewport everything shows up correctly**, and `layout_gravity` can be set to anything. Secondly, at first glance **`match_parent` is treated as `wrap_content` so content can be measured taller than viewport**.

Comment: 2/3 @BenP. Here's the catch: When the content exceeds the viewport (*is measured* to be bigger) **what you see follows `layout_gravity`**. If it's `center` top and bottom will appear cut off. If it's `bottom` content will appear to be bottom aligned. The problem is **the scrolling mechanism still thinks that top left corner of content starts at top left corner of viewport** - and allows you to only scroll downwards from the initial position. The amount by which you can scroll is calculated "correctly" as height that exceeds the top of viewport + height that exceeds the bottom of viewport.

Comment: 3/3 @BenP. So here you go: `layout_gravity` affects the child layout position - this is the same in `ScrollView` and `FrameLayout`. But the scrolling part does not see this and assumes [0, 0] of content to be at [0, 0] of scroll view. You can scroll the correct amount but it's going to be offset (unless `layout_gravity="top"` or equivalent).

Comment: @EugenPechanec Thank you very much. That's a clear explanation and makes perfect sense.